# Alias Declarations in C++

Tags: c++

I have come across this code snippet and have no idea what it means:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
 using test = int(int a, int b); 

 return 0;
}
```

I can guess `test` can be used instead of `int(int a, int b)`, but what does `int(int a, int b)` even mean? is it a function? How can it be used?

Answer (score 1):

`int(int a, int b)` is a function declaration that has two parameters of the type `int` and the return type also `int`.

You can use this alias declaration for example as a member function declarations of a class or using it in a parameter declaration.

Comment: I see, how can it be defined then? why would some one write it like this? just write a normal function.

Comment: @Josh Because it's much simpler to pass `test` to a function than `int(int a, int b)`, e.g. `int mySort(int a, int b, test f) { return f(a, b); }`

Comment: but how can it be defined with a body?

Comment: @Josh It's not an alias to a function. It's an alias to a function signature. It has no body.

Comment: @ThomasSablik you can't pass a function as a parameter. You can pass a function pointer

Comment: @Ayxan where did I say _pass a function as a parameter_? `test` is a function pointer in my example.

Comment: @Thomas my bad, sorry

Answer (score 1):

It's an alias for a function signature.

A more complete usage is to declare a pointer or reference to a function

```
int foo(int, int);

int main()
{
     using test = int(int a, int b);   // identifiers a and b are optional
     test *fp = &foo;      
     test *fp2 = foo;     // since the name of function is implicitly converted to a pointer
     test &fr = foo;   

     test foo;     // another declaration of foo, local to the function

     fp(1,2);        // will call foo(1,2)
     fp2(3,4);       // will call foo(3,4)
     fr(5,6);        // will call foo(5,6)
     foo(7,8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give another use option of this line, with lambda expressions:

```
int main() {
    using test = int(int, int);
    test le = [](int a, int b) -> int {
        return a + b;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

One point that you have to keep in mind about this use of test, there are probably more efficient ways to declare a function signature, like `auto` in lambda expressions case, `template` in case of passing function as argument to another function, etc.

This way came all the way from pure C programming, with the `using` twist. I won't recommend of choosing this way, but for general understanding it is always good to know more than the correct ways.